# What is the correct public access config for s3 bucket to access from lambda with http proxy integration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have an **s3** bucket and I want to upload a file from a lambda that is invoked through an API call but I don't know what is the correct config for blocking public access configuration setting of the **s3** bucket. Now, none of the 4 options are checked and it works but I'm not sure about it considering the security aspects.

What is the correct configuration of policy bucket, IAM role and blocking public access for upload a file to s3 using an http call?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appropriate configuration is:

- Lambda function IAM role: permit s3:PutObject to s3://mybucket/myprefix/*
- Lambda function: use AWS SDK to invoke PutObject to S3

The S3 bucket policy and S3 block public access settings are largely orthogonal to the Lambda requirement here. In the typical case, you should use standard best practices: do not have an S3 bucket policy at all (unless you specifically need it) and enable Block Public Access at the account level (unless you specifically need buckets to be public).

Comment: Thanks you,  I put in **on** these two options:

- Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new public bucket or access point policies

- Block public and cross-account access to buckets and objects through any public bucket or access point policies

Is that correct?

Comment: No. That will allow individual objects to have a public-read ACL. Just check the top-level box for all 4, unless you have a specific reason not to.

Comment: What should I check if i want to show the files (images) in a website?

Comment: First thing I would say is that ideally you should not mix public and non-public content in the same bucket. If you need files to be accessible on the web to unauthenticated users, then you have to make the objects public - personally I would do that through S3 bucket policy. You won't be able to block public access in that case. If the files are to be made available via some web application that you have written then they don't have to be public - the webapp can serve them to authenticated users directly or via pre-signed URLs.